# Windows Core audio API

Tags: windows, core-audio, volume, audio

I'm developing an windows application which needs to get the sound output level of the current audio device. I'm currently doing this using windows core audio API - EndpointVolume API (IAudioMeterInformations). The application checks the sound output level every 10ms and does its own logic according to the level.

The key of the app is to manipulate the sound before it reaches the speakers (so when you here it, it was already processed).. The current solutions (using EndpointVolume) kind of  does this but it processes the sound which **WAS** already played.. but i would like to process the sound **just before it is played**.

Would it be better to use the peak meter from DeviceTopology API in stead of the peak meter in AudioEndpoint API?

I am asking this because the applications needs to react as fast as possible to the sound output level, so the manipulation wont be noticeable. So i though if i would use DeviceTopology (which is placed before the Endpoint device) it would make it more responsive and less noticeable?

Is my assumption correct or am i barking the wrong tree?

Comment: Polling is required, no magic available.  Best stick to the SDK sample, it isn't simple code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316561.aspx

Comment: yes i know, but i think you misunderstood my question. If you look at the msdn reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370851%28v=VS.85%29.aspx you will see you have DeviceTopology and AudioEndpoint API and both have support for Peak Meters. Would it be better to use DeviceTopology API (it is located before the endpoint device on this image http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC99537.jpg)

Comment: yes i know, the device topology SDK docs doesn't have any code samples.  Don't hesitate to post an answer when you find out.  I haven't seen Larry Osterman around lately, the Man that Knows.

Comment: i've read the whole sound core api documentation and most likely they both use the same peak meter values. Endpoint Volume API uses a hardware peak meter (if exists) and so does DeviceTopology API, thus in my opinion using Device topology wouldn't improve anything :\ should i post a full explanation?